# How do I add !DOCTYPE to my html with groovy

Tags: html, groovy, doctype

I would like to add the following DOCTYPE to my html email with groovy.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional //EN" http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

My groovycode starts like this:

```
def responseDoc = job.addDocument("ECommerce_test.html"){out ->
def xmlWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(out)
MarkupBuilder html = new MarkupBuilder(xmlWriter)
```

I have tried to use the MarkupBuilderHelper, but I don' whant the xml-declaration.
This is the code I have used with MarkupBuilderHelper and it doesn't seems to work without the declaration.

```
def helper = new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilderHelper(xml)
helper.xmlDeclaration([version:'1.0', encoding:'UTF-8', standalone:'no'])
helper.yieldUnescaped """<!DOCTYPE note SYSTEM "note.dtd">"""
```

/Therese

Comment: Just prepending that string on the final document is out of the question?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.  Sorry. :-|

Comment: You should be able to use StreamingMarkupBuilder

Comment: Could you please show me how?

Comment: @Therese added a potential answer :-) . Fingers crossed!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this with StreamingMarkupBuilder?

```
import groovy.xml.*

def responseDoc = job.addDocument("ECommerce_test.html"){out ->
    out << new StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind {
        mkp.yieldUnescaped '<?xml version="1.0", encoding="UTF-8", standalone="no"?>\n'
        mkp.yieldUnescaped '<!DOCTYPE note SYSTEM "note.dtd">\n'
        html {
            body {
                h1('WOW!')
            }
        }
    }
}
```

An alternaive:

```
import groovy.xml.*

job.addDocument("ECommerce_test.html"){out ->
    new StringWriter().with { sw ->
        new MarkupBuilder(sw).html {
            body {
                h1('WOW!')
            }
        }
        out << '<!DOCTYPE note SYSTEM "note.dtd">\n' << sw.toString()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time. This worked in the same way as with the MarkupBuilderHelper. I get the xml-header and I would like to just have the DOCTYPE.

Comment: @Therese get rid of the `mkp.yieldUnescaped '<?xml version="1.0", encoding="UTF-8", standalone="no"?>\n'` line?

Comment: I have tried your solution and it do work, but all formatting such as new line dissapear. The html displays in one long line of text. But maby I have to accept that. You win some and you loose some?! :-) Is it because you use the StreamingMarkupBuilder istead of the MarkupBuilder?

Comment: @Therese added an alternative that uses MarkupBuilder, but prefixes it with a doctype string

Answer (score 1):

It does look like a bug. `yieldUnescaped` works within a closure (within a tag), or after xml declaration, but not for generating a first top level statement.

Comment: I'd ask why do you care to have the xmlDeclaration? It can't hurt, can it?

Comment: I thought it may make a different when opening mejl in different clients. But I don't know if it matters.

Comment: It shouldn't hurt. It is actually the right thing to do.

Comment: @JBaruch If you want to write `<!DOCTYPE html>` to signal an HTML 5 document, you probably don't want the XML declaration. The content of an HTML 5 document does not have to be valid (or even well-formed) XML. The declaration could cause browsers to treat your document differently in some circumstances.